# Prevent Vue 2 from re-rendering an array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was playing with the data grid component and added a new column, called **cool** which is boolean.

Now if I want to sort by this column and if change a value after sorting (click Not true), it immediately re-sorts the data, making rows to switch position which is undesirable (it should happen only on another click).

Is it possible to prevent immediate sorting / keep vue from re-rendering the table?

I've also read somewhere that Vue doesn't register changing arrays by index but for some reason it does [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xkkbfL3L/1838/1)?

```js
// register the grid component
Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  props: {
    data: Array,
    columns: Array,
    filterKey: String
  },
  data: function () {
    var sortOrders = {}
    this.columns.forEach(function (key) {
      sortOrders[key] = 1
    })
    return {
      sortKey: '',
      sortOrders: sortOrders
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredData: function () {
      var sortKey = this.sortKey
      var filterKey = this.filterKey && this.filterKey.toLowerCase()
      var order = this.sortOrders[sortKey] || 1
      var data = this.data
      if (filterKey) {
        data = data.filter(function (row) {
          return Object.keys(row).some(function (key) {
            return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) > -1
          })
        })
      }
      if (sortKey) {
        data = data.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
          a = a[sortKey]
          b = b[sortKey]
          return (a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1) * order
        })
      }
      return data
    }
  },
  filters: {
    capitalize: function (str) {
      return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function (key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    }
  }
})

// bootstrap the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: ['name', 'power', 'cool'],
    gridData: [
      { name: 'Chuck Norris', power: Infinity, cool: true },
      { name: 'Bruce Lee', power: 9000, cool: true },
      { name: 'Jackie Chan', power: 7000, cool: false },
      { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000, cool: false }
    ]
  }, 
  methods: {
   notTrue() {
     this.gridData[0].cool = !this.gridData[0].cool;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid #42b983;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

th {
  background-color: #42b983;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.66);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

td {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

th, td {
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

th.active {
  color: #fff;
}

th.active .arrow {
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.66;
}

.arrow.asc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}

.arrow.dsc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<!-- component template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="key in columns"
          @click="sortBy(key)"
          :class="{ active: sortKey == key }">
          {{ key | capitalize }}
          <span class="arrow" :class="sortOrders[key] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'">
          </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="entry in filteredData">
        <td v-for="key in columns">
          {{entry[key]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>

<!-- demo root element -->
<div id="demo">
  <form id="search">
    Search <input name="query" v-model="searchQuery">
  </form>
  <demo-grid
    :data="gridData"
    :columns="gridColumns"
    :filter-key="searchQuery">
  </demo-grid>
  
  <a @click="notTrue()">Not true</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

computed variables are recalculate when its changed.

so if you won't recalculate filteredData when it changes, you need to put *filteredData* to **data**

and create method that makes ordered data and put *filteredData*

and then, put that function to trigger when th is clicked.

Comment: I seem not to understand. Can you please elaborate?